# in_reply_to_user_id always being returned as null

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, twitter

Hi all I am trying to reply to a particular tweet via my app. Here is the code  :

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[parameters setObject:[[myAccount.currentTweet objectForKey:@"id"]stringValue]     
forKey:@"in_reply_to_status_id_str"];

SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter   
requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL  
URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"] 
parameters:parameters];`
```

Here's what Twitter API JSON is returning me when reply is successfully posted

`"id_str" = 337918014110433281;"in_reply_to_screen_name" = geochirpr;"in_reply_to_status_id" = "<null>";"in_reply_to_status_id_str" = "<null>";"in_reply_to_user_id" = 1378947649;"in_reply_to_user_id_str" = 1378947649;`

As you can see in reply to "in_reply_to_user_id" is populated but funnily enough,"in_reply_to_status_id" remains null. Even though I pass the "in_reply_to_status_id" parameters also I've included the @username. Still wouldnt work!!!

HELPPPPPP!!!

Comment: I believe its happening because I am using SLComposeViewController to post the reply!! Im not able to establish the connection between `"in_reply_to_user_id"` in the SLComposeViewController. hence a new tweet is being generated each time with no `in_reply_to_user_id`

Answer (score 0):

Try [parameters setValue: rather than setObject on your second line.